# Rails is not allowing to add data in more than 60000 cells approximately?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel

In my Rails app, I have n report generation function, where I have around 200-300k records which needs to be downloaded as excel report. But the problem is that during excel generation (if there are more than 62000 records approximately), I get partial data in the report. Any solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Classic" Excel (XLS) has a magic limit of 65535 rows per worksheet. This was fixed in XLSX but the version used by the Spreadsheet gem can only write XLS files.

If you want to write more data, consider hacking around it using `in_groups_of` and writing multiple column sets of your data (i.e. split 1 block of 3 columns and 100000 rows into 4 blocks of 3 (12 in total) columns and 25000 rows).

You can do this until you reach the other limit of 256 columns. After that, open up a new workbook or consider a better file type.

As an alternative, you could switch to [axlsx](https://github.com/randym/axlsx), which supports writing XLSX files – and does that really fast, too.

[[source]](http://makandracards.com/makandra/3115-excel-files-can-t-hold-more-than-65535-rows-per-worksheet)

Comment: Thanks @Dusht, will try it out and let you know.

Comment: @Sahil In the tutorial you shared, it has typo in `package.workboook`. Notice the extra `o` in workbook. Hope it resolves your error.

Comment: Thanks, got that. There are few typos in that tutorial.

Comment: Thanks a lot, implemented it, managed to add data to more than 1lakh cells now.